AWS Glue Writing to Opensearch
I have an Opensearch managed cluster, and I want to use AWS Glue to migrate hundreds of data in batch from Redshift to Opensearch.
I have followed these steps to

create an AWS Glue connection to Opensearch, with appropriate IAM role (AmazonOpenSearchServiceFullAccess) and secrets (username and password)
create ETL job using AWS Glue Visual ETL

My Opensearch cluster is on public network access. Despite this, I get the error
Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; Failed Line Number: 20; An error occurred while calling o134.getSink. Unable to execute HTTP request: Network is unreachable

The failing line of code is generated by my AWS Glue Visual ETL
AmazonOpenSearchService_node1733461823015 = 
  glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=AmazonRedshift_node1733461813643, 
    connection_type="opensearch", 
    connection_options={"opensearch.resource": "taxi", "connectionName": "opensearch-connection"}, 
    transformation_ctx="AmazonOpenSearchService_node1733461823015"
)

Does anyone have any ideas how to move forward?
